# how to declare member variable as extended type in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, typescript

Is there a way to define a "member variable" as an "extension object" instead of a static type (without using an interface)?

Simply something like this pseudocode:

```
class Foo {

    bar -> extends Rectangle;
    constructor(barInstance:IRectangle){
       this.bar = barInstance;

       this.bar.getArea(); //<-- is code completed because interface IRectangle

       // no type error
       this.bar.someCustomFunction = function() {
       }
    }

}
```

instead of

```
class Foo {
    bar: IRectangle;
    //or
    bar:Rectangle;
}
```

This way I can add properties not defined on the base class or interface without getting type errors, but also get code completion from the base class. Heh, *lazy* strict typing?

Answer (score 2):

Intersection Types

```
interface IRectangle {
    getArea: () => number;
}

class Foo {
    bar: IRectangle & { [key: string]: any; };

    constructor(barInstance:IRectangle){
       this.bar = barInstance;

       this.bar.getArea(); //<-- is code completed because interface IRectangle

       // no type error
       this.bar.someCustomFunction = function() {
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a constrained generic type parameter.

```
interface Base {
  prop: number;
}

interface Child extends Base {
  thing: string;
}

class Foo<T extends Base> {
  bar: T
}

var foo = new Foo<Child>();
foo.bar.thing; // now permitted by the type checker
```

Comment: i want to do this without having to explicitly define 'thing' but dynamically assign it without raising type error, but also get code hints... kind of like this.bar.thing = () =>{ return true ;} essentially, typing to <any> OR <IRectangle>

Comment: If you make your class take an instance of the generic type as a constructor argument you can write an object literal for instance and have its type be inferred. I'm not sure there is a solution for assigning new properties after instantiation and getting type checking for them. Those kinds of patterns tend to befuddle static analysis.

Comment: If it's really necessary to tack on additional properties later, I would make them optional members of a named interface.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure that I understand you, but if so then something like this:

```
interface IRectangle {
    getArea(): void;
}

class Rectangle implements IRectangle {
    getArea(): void {}
    someCustomFunction(): void {}
}

class Foo<T extends IRectangle> {
    bar: T;

    constructor(barInstance: T){
        this.bar = barInstance;
        this.bar.getArea();

        // no type error
        if (this.bar instanceof Rectangle) {
            (this.bar as any as Rectangle).someCustomFunction = function() {}
        }
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IRectangle%20%7B%0A%09getArea()%3A%20void%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Rectangle%20implements%20IRectangle%20%7B%0A%09getArea()%3A%20void%20%7B%7D%0A%09someCustomFunction()%3A%20void%20%7B%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Foo%3CT%20extends%20IRectangle%3E%20%7B%0A%09bar%3A%20T%3B%0A%09%0A%09constructor(barInstance%3A%20T)%7B%0A%09%09this.bar%20%3D%20barInstance%3B%0A%09%09this.bar.getArea()%3B%0A%09%09%0A%09%09%2F%2F%20no%20type%20error%0A%09%09if%20(this.bar%20instanceof%20Rectangle)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09(this.bar%20as%20any%20as%20Rectangle).someCustomFunction%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%7D))