# Typescript - declaring a variable as a type which extends an interface

Tags: typescript, types, interface, typescript-generics, type-annotation

Let's say I have an *interface* called `MyIFace`.
Is there any way to **declare** a member property of a type which extends that very interface using *type annotation*?
I try to post a pseudo-code of what I'm searching for:

```
class Foo {
    x: any extends MyIface;               //this is what I'd like to write

    // some code here...
}
```

[This previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38985570/how-to-declare-member-variable-as-extended-type-in-typescript) talks about **intersection types**, which apparently seems to be fine (the compiler doesn't complain) but in the end it's not what I need. Indeed, declaring `x: any & MyIFace;` doesn't resemble the structure I need: it states that x has both *any* and *MyIFace* blueprints, while I want to state that x has a blueprint of *any* which extends the blueprint of *MyIFace*.

Comment: I'm unsure of what you want to accomplish. Since interfaces are implicitly implemented in TypeScript, anything that satisfies the MyIface Interface will work if you just declare the variable to be of type MyIface (without the use of any).

Comment: @pascalpuetz yes, but then if I try to access some property not defined in `MyIFace` but only on the type which extends it, the compiler of course raises an error like `Property "someProperty" does not exist on type  "MyIFace"`. That's why I also need to use *any*

Comment: Ah I see. In that case, you could intersect with an index signature type `MyIface & {[key:string]:any}`. But honestly, if you know what properties you want to access, I heavily suggest using a new type for that that actually extends your interface. Or you could use typecasting to any `(foo.x as any).bar = 'This is a new field';` and still declare `x: MyIface`.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure whether you are looking for somthing to combine two types in typescript. Suppose if you have type A and type B , you want to have both the properties in A and B to be available in another property C. You can make it like , type C = A & B

Comment: @pascalpuetz that worked as I intended. Thank you. I need this kind of interpolation because I don't know exactly what properties will have the objects which will extends `MyIFace`

Comment: @CodeBuggy you're right but I'd like to avoid declaring a new type. I just need that annotation once

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe you just need:

```
class Foo {
    x?: MyIface & Record<string, any>;
    // some code here...
}
```

Comment: Not really. I was looking for *x* extending *MyIFace*. @pascalpuetz probably solved in the comment

Comment: @dc_Bita98 so you're saying that any subtype of `MyIface` is an acceptable type for `x`?

Comment: yes, stressing out that x may extend the interface/class. More a formal matter than a useful one

Comment: @dc_Bita98 still trying to understand this. Are you implying that a valid type for `x` does _not necessarily_ have to inherit from `MyIface`, but rather it should contain the same properties as `MyIface` (and possibly others)?

Comment: exactly. The third comment in the previous answer explains the concept well in my opinion